# How to convert extended class from DailyRollingFileAppender to Log4j 2

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm using now Log4j and want to start using Log4j 2.

I want to create some appender that will do couple things (like create zip file from the log file) daily, and if the file exceeded some size.

In Log4j I had `DailyRollingFileAppanderAndZipping` class that extended the `DailyRollingFileAppender` and performed everything that I needed.

How can I implement something like this in Log4j 2? 
I saw that there is `RollingFileAppender` but I can't extend from it, it is `final` class.

Comment: AFAIK RollingFIleAppender can do all of that. "If the file pattern ends with ".gz", ".zip", ".bz2", ".deflate", ".pack200", or ".xz" the resulting archive will be compressed using the compression scheme that matches the suffix." And rolling on fileSize is done by using the SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.

Comment: [Docu](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) - scroll down to RollingFileAppender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Fildor, I used RollingFIleAppender. It is working very well.